# One day I [do something] and another day I [don't]

Tags: prepositions

Could somebody help to understand if it is possible to use the phrase in the title in situations when you change you mind on certain subject, for example: "I can't decide on my future career. One day I dream of becoming a doctor, and another day I want to be a pilot." I wonder if I need to use preposition 'on' in this case. 
Thanks for your advice.

Comment: If by *sth* you mean *something*, please spell out the actual word.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the preposition. But I would edit the tenses used in your sentence: "I can't decide on my future career. One day I **dreamt** of becoming a doctor, and another day I **wanted** to be a pilot."

Answer (score 0):

"I can't decide on my future career. One day I dream of becoming a doctor, *on* another I want to be a pilot." *On* is necessary, the second *day* is not, and *and* is optional.

An alternative way to express that would be the following: "I can't decide on my future career. One day I dream of becoming a doctor, the next a pilot."

Comment: In your first sentence if you omit the _and_ it is a run-on sentence. Of course run-ons are actually not uncommon in informal writing, but I would not recommend it in any formal writing. Easy solution: semicolon.